# C# Extract that removes from source as many records as many in second

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, extract

We have two arrays

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

I am looking for **Linq** (not necessary) method that accepts these two collections and returns

```
{ 1, 1, 3 }
```

The problems is that `Intersect` returns  `{ 3 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute frequencies of the items to remove (`arr2`) and then remove them from `arr1`

```
var freq = arr2
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

var result = arr1
  .Where(item => !freq.ContainsKey(item) || --freq[item] >= 0)
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing from first array all items from second one:

```
var a1 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var a2 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
a2.ForEach(x => a1.Remove(x));
```

Comment: I do not lithe the idea to mutate the collection.

Comment: @BasilKosovan you can always copy a list... This is very short and simple solution perfect for small data/one time code. It may be slow for long lists due to O(len_list_one * len_list_two) nature - optimal solution is O(len_list_one + len_list_two).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want LINQ-only solution: compute frequency for both, and than reconstruct the list skipping corresponding count of items from the second list. If you want to preserver order re-ordering based on the original index is an option... but at that point I'd simply resort to filtering the list without LINQ.

```
var a1 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var a2 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var second = a2.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=> g.Count()); 
var result = a1.GroupBy(x=>x)
   .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(second.ContainsKey(g.Key)? second[g.Key] : 0));
```

I'd go with filtering (also Remove-based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77346790/477420) by Michał Turczyn is easier to read despite being potentially too slow for large lists due to O(len_list_one * len_list_two) nature).

Code below is O(len_list_one + len_list_two) and preserves the order from the first list:

```
var second = a2.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=> g.Count()); 
var result = new List<int>();
foreach(var x in a1)
{
   if (second.TryGetValue(x, out var count) && count > 0)
   {
      second[x] --;
   }
   else
   {
     result.Add(x);
   }
}
```